# Running multi-node kubernetes using docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I followed the instructions given [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.html), but both the scripts (master.sh & worker.sh) are failing on nodes (Ubuntu 14.04). The script output is as follows:

```
root@LAP0061:/home/user/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode# ./master.sh 
K8S_VERSION is set to: 1.2.0-alpha.7
ETCD_VERSION is set to: 2.2.1
FLANNEL_VERSION is set to: 0.5.5
FLANNEL_IFACE is set to: eth0
FLANNEL_IPMASQ is set to: true
MASTER_IP is set to: 192.168.1.19
ARCH is set to: amd64
Detecting your OS distro ...
Starting bootstrap docker ...
Starting k8s ...
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.
root@LAP0061:/home/user/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode#
```

But, when I run the command "service docker status", it shows "docker start/running, process 9559". So, why is it giving the error message even if the docker is running?

```
Versions:
Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS on both master and worker
Kubernetes: v1.2.0
hyperkube: v1.2.0
Docker: 1.10.2
```

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see an error in /var/log/docker-bootstrap.log ? It is possible docker did not come up properly in bootsrtap docker step.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for prompt reply! The /var/log/docker-bootstrap.log contains a single line saying: "flag provided but not defined: -d"

Comment: Is this error related to docker version. Actually, there is a note [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.html) as:  "Note: There is a bug in Docker 1.7.0 that prevents this from working correctly. Please install Docker 1.6.2 or Docker 1.7.1".  So, should I downgrade my docker to any of these versions (1.6.2/1.7.1)

Comment: You can try with k8: 1.1 and docker 1.9